# QGIS: Calculation of area percentage is above 100 %

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

[image]When I use the field calculator it gives me a value above 100 % (Pic. 1, red mark).
As you see in the picture the result is at 100,05 %. At other calculations its even higher, sometimes up to 100,25 %. When I change the command from `($area / sum(area))*100` to `(round("$area",5) / round("sum(area)",5))*100` it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are encountering may be laying in the different calculation methods of `$area` and `area($geometry)`. We do not know how your field `"area"` was calculated, but to get your accurate percentage, I recommend to either recaluclate the fieldvalue of `"area"` by using `$area` or use another method in your new calculation. (Like the one [@Babel suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408520/qgis-calculation-of-area-percentage-is-above-100/408521#comment664860_408521): `($area / sum($area))*100` or `area($geometry) / sum(area($geometry)))*100`)

From the docs:

> $area Returns the area of the current feature. The area calculated by
> this function respects both the current project's ellipsoid setting
> and area unit settings. For example, if an ellipsoid has been set for
> the project then the calculated area will be ellipsoidal, and if no
> ellipsoid is set then the calculated area will be planimetric.
>
> area($geometry) Returns the area of a geometry polygon object.
> Calculations are always planimetric in the Spatial Reference System
> (SRS) of this geometry, and the units of the returned area will match
> the units for the SRS. This differs from the calculations performed by
> the $area function, which will perform ellipsoidal calculations based
> on the project's ellipsoid and area unit settings.